# File system for storage in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hard-drive, filesystems

Recently I bought a new HDD for my Mac, but I'm not sure which file system would be best for storing large amounts of data.

Since NTFS isn't supported natively in OS X (10.8) I was looking into ExFAT. But according to different sources it wouldn't be the best solution.

The reason I don't want to use HFS+ is that I had bad experiences with storing and sharing data. It does a lot of requests to my HDD and it results in lots of noise.

Right now I'm using NTFS with the Paragon driver. Would it be better to switch to ExFAT or something else, or stay with NTFS?

Comment: What are the "sources" that claim using ExFAT is not the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it primarily with a Mac, then avoid the overhead of NTFS, and go with ext4.

Paragon should be able to read ext4 without a problem. If you want to use it on Windows also, then best to stick with NTFS, even though exFAT *will* give better performance, I wouldn't trust it on a Mac just yet.

Comment: no, i wont use it with windows, just for mac

Comment: Why wouldn't you trust ExFAT on OS X? In contrast to ext4, which only works with FUSE drivers on OS X, ExFAT is natively supported there.

Comment: @slhck Nothing against ExFAT personally really, I've used it in the past, but since it's still pretty new (2006 on Windows, even newer on Mac), I'm not sure if I trust it for huge data storage just yet, I'd lean more towards a *based fs, especially since it has a larger max volume size :-), in case wants to store an EiB of files....